# "Knights and Knaves" puzzle to solve using equivalences.

Tags: logic, puzzle

**Context for the puzzle:**

You are on an island inhabited by knights and knaves. Knights always tell the truth, knaves always lie. You meet 5 natives:

- Carl says "I am the same type as Peter".
- Zippy says "Carl is a Knave or Jack is a Knight".
- Jack says "I am a knight and Bill is a Knave".
- Peter says "Bill is a Knight".
- Bill says "I am a Knight and so is Carl"

**From this, I have formulated the following equivalences:**

1. C ≡ P
2. Z ≡ ¬C ∨ J
3. J ≡ J ∧ ¬B
4. P ≡ B
5. B ≡ B ∧ C

I am trying to deduce which of the people are knights and which are knaves, however, after doing some substitution and manipulation using logical laws, I get to a point where I cannot make any more simplification and hence get stuck.

Could someone please point me in the right direction towards solving this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not $C ≡ P$ - that would be true in the case of both $C$ and $P$ being knaves. You want $C ≡ (C ≡ P)$, which simplifies to simply $P$.

Comment: Is ≡ the right symbol here? It feels like we should simply be using =.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have reached the conclusion that C,P,B are true and Z,J are false - Carl, Peter and Bill are knights while Zippy and Jack are knaves. Would that be correct?

Comment: Looks right to me.